# Using Access 2007, how to delete partially duplicate records in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Table 1 looks like this ...

```
Episode | Pgm | admitdate | dischargedate
_________________________________________
2345      170   1/19/12     00/00/00
2345      170   9/1/00      00/00/00
6789      110   10/20/11    12/10/11
6789      110   12/01/11    01/01/12
3456      170   10/12/93    00/00/00
3456      170   9/1/00      00/00/00
```

Table 1 should look like this ... (only duplicate records with dischargedate = "00/00/00" will be processed and admitdate with maximum will be deleted, those with existing dischargedate will be ignored and not deleted)

```
Episode | Pgm | admitdate | dischargedate
_________________________________________
2345      170   9/1/00      00/00/00
6789      110   10/20/11    12/10/11
6789      110   12/01/11    01/01/12
3456      170   10/12/93    00/00/00
```

If I do the SELECT QUERY and group the 3 fields (episode, pgm, dischargedate with criteria = "00/00/00") and set admitdate to MIN, it shows me the records to be deleted but once I make this to a DELETE QUERY, it deletes all the records with duplicate episode, pgm, and dischargedate = "00/00/00".  What would be the best way to tackle this?

Thanks!